# Where should I put my static text files in order to be OTPy?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, rebar, cowboy

I'm building a server with [cowboy](https://github.com/extend/cowboy), and I've got some static HTML pages that I want to serve. Is there an OTP friendly place to put that sort of thing? Is there an established way to tell rebar where to look for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the pages are part of the application, then typically under the priv directory, for example priv/docroot or similar. I don't know about rebar, but in general, `filename:join(code:priv_dir(?APPNAME), "docroot")` could be used to compute the full directory name at runtime.